# replace /g not working when used with map method

Tags: javascript

I have a set of arrays and I'm trying to change the dash on the dates to a slashes but the replace /g is not working when I use it in a map method.

```
let set1 = [['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6-3-1975', 'Red'],
['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4-2-1979', 'Green'],
['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12-2-1973', 'Black']]

set1.map(arr => arr[3].replace(/-/g, "/"))
console.log(set1)
```

The result should be as shown bellow but the dashes are not changing

```
['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6/3/1975', 'Red'],
['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4/2/1979', 'Green'],
['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12/2/1973', 'Black']
```

Comment: What is the updated output?

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not mutate the original array. You have to assign the result after mapping back to `set1`.

You'll also have to assign the result after replacing back to the item at index `3` and return `arr` in the map function.

```js
let set1 = [['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6-3-1975', 'Red'],
['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4-2-1979', 'Green'],
['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12-2-1973', 'Black']]

set1 = set1.map(arr => (arr[3] = arr[3].replace(/-/g, "/"), arr))
console.log(set1)
```

If you don't want to create a new one, use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
let set1 = [['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6-3-1975', 'Red'],
['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4-2-1979', 'Green'],
['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12-2-1973', 'Black']]

set1.forEach(arr => arr[3] = arr[3].replace(/-/g, "/"))
console.log(set1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another answer, but using `forEach` instead. This may use less memory compared to the `map` approach.

```js
let set1 = [['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6-3-1975', 'Red'],
['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4-2-1979', 'Green'],
['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12-2-1973', 'Black']]

set1.forEach(arr => arr[3] = arr[3].replace(/-/g, "/"))

console.log(set1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.map()` function expects you to return the *entire* element you want to be in the resulting array.  So, you need to return the entire `arr` value, not just the date string.

```js
let set1 = [
  ['Jones', 'Ann', 'F', '6-3-1975', 'Red'],
  ['Perez', 'Maria', 'F', '4-2-1979', 'Green'],
  ['Samuels', 'Rika', 'M', '12-2-1973', 'Black']
];

set1 = set1.map(arr => {
  arr[3] = arr[3].replace(/-/g, "/");
  return arr;
});

console.log(set1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mutate the original arrays, then you have to rebuild new arrays like this:

```js
let set1 = [
  ["Jones", "Ann", "F", "6-3-1975", "Red"],
  ["Perez", "Maria", "F", "4-2-1979", "Green"],
  ["Samuels", "Rika", "M", "12-2-1973", "Black"],
];

const replace = (index) => (set) =>
  set.map((arr) =>
    Object.assign([], arr, { [index]: arr[index].replace(/-/g, "/") })
  );

const replaceThirdIndex = replace(3);

console.log(replaceThirdIndex(set1));
```